# iTextSharp export GridView error if empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, itext

I downloaded the last version of [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) dll. I use this for export in PDF one `GridView` in c#. But it could be that the `GridView` is empty.

When the `GridView` is empty and try the export on `PDF` I have this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

On this line on the bold line on code below:

```
if (rowCountProducts > 0)
{
    table.HeaderRows = 1;
}
else
{
    table.HeaderRows = 0;
}
```

How to resolve this?

Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You posted a link to SourceForge, but iTextSharp move to GitHub: https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/releases. For now, the files are still synced from GitHub to SourceForge, but who knows what will happen in the future, if the SF service keeps degrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
if (rowCountProducts > 0)
{
    table.HeaderRows = 1;
}
else
{
    table.HeaderRows = 0;
}
```

with:

```
if (rowCountProducts > 0)
{
    table.HeaderRows = 1;
}
```

You don't need to set the `HeaderRows` value if you don't have any rows.

Comment: Thanks, but now I have the same ertor on : `pdfDoc.Add(table);`
`

Comment: If the table has no rows: don't add it!